# Complex sql query with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

**Customers**

```
ID_CUSTOMER
NAME
```

**Products**

```
ID_PRODUCT
PRODUCTNAME
PRICE
```

**Orders**

```
ID_ORDER
CUSTOMER_ID
PRODUCT_ID
QUANTITY
```

How to select all customers who ordered for $10k or more?

Comment: @Ask: Check answers provided. Comment accordingly for your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
SELECT C.ID_CUSTOMER, C.Name, 
      SUM(P.PRICE * O.QUANTITY) AS Total FROM Customers C 
      JOIN Orders O ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = O.CUSTOMER_ID
      JOIN Procucts P ON P.PRODUCT_ID = O.PRODUCT_ID
      GROUP BY C.ID_CUSTOMER, C.Name
      HAVING SUM(P.PRICE * O.QUANTITY) >= 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.*
from customers c
inner join orders o on o.customer_id = c.id_customer
inner join products p on p.id_product = o.product_id
group by c.id_customer
having sum(p.price * o.quantity) >= 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 SELECT   a.ID_CUSTOMER, 
          a.NAME
   FROM   CUSTOMERS a
            INNER JOIN ORDERS b 
              ON b.CUSTOMER_ID = a.ID_CUSTOMER
            INNER JOIN PRODUCTS c
              ON c.ID_PRODUCT = b.product_id
GROUP BY  a.ID_CUSTOMER, a.NAME
  HAVING  SUM(c.PRICE * b.QUANTITY) >= 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not really a complex query. Another syntax to do the same thing:

```
SELECT C.ID_CUSTOMER, C.NAME, SUM(P.PRICE * O.QUANTITY) TOTAL
  FROM Products P, Customers C, Orders O
 WHERE O.CUSTOMER_ID = C.ID_CUSTOMER 
   AND O.PRODUCT_ID = P.ID_PRODUCT
 GROUP BY C.ID_CUSTOMER, C.NAME
HAVING SUM(P.PRICE * O.QUANTITY) >= 10000
```